# How to place two <a> tags side by side within a JSP

Tags: html, jsp

How do I align two `<a>` tags which include a list to show side by side on my JSP? Even when they are not within a `<div>`.

Comment: Add your code. What are you trying so far?

Comment: I am just try certain tags like <centre> etc it aligns them but I need them side by side due to requirements change. @Sachink

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lists are, by default, `display: block`. So they generate block boxes.

There are various ways to put them side by side, but the usual one is to make them display as inline blocks.

Since you want the links to wrap around them, make the links display as inline boxes instead.

```css
a { display: inline-block; }
```

```html
<a href="http://example.com">
  <ul>
    <li>Alice</li>
    <li>Bob</li>
  </ul>
</a>

<a href="http://example.com">
  <ul>
    <li>Alice</li>
    <li>Bob</li>
  </ul>
</a>
```

The fact you are generating your HTML from JSP is irrelevant. The browser only sees the client side code.